# Calling PHP var from Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a variable in PHP called `$total = $db['total'];`

now I want to grab that in Jquery so I do

```
<script>
$(function() {               
  console.log("<?php echo $total; ?>");


});

</script>
```

but I get some nonsense like `console.log("<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">` throws error uncaught syntaxError: Unexpected identifier. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does it show if you echo it outside the js?

Comment: @Dagon the correct total.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
console.log("<?php echo $total; ?>");
```

use

```
console.log(<?php echo json_encode($total); ?>);
```

because the value of `$total` needs to be escaped before being handed over to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You `most likely` have an error in your php syntax! I'm sure of it, but hey there's a remote possibility that you actually have that string in your variable, so I'm choosing the safe path of saying most likely.

A simple googling of the string:

> `<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">`

Gives you a ton of sites which have errors in them, so I'd guess thats your problem. Other than that, but I guess you allready know this, you must be careful that the php-string that you're echoing out doesn't `break` the JS-string.

So how to solve this? Well, my first guess is that the variable `$total` doesn't actually exist, so check that first. This is ofcourse just guessing since I haven't seen your php-code.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a kludge and, at the very least, inelegant, but last time I had a problem like this I got so confused I ended up writing the values into a hidden element with php then reading them in jquery.

Not pretty, but it worked. I actually had to deal with an array so dumped the whole thing into a table.